# How to create and rotate Automatic Snapshot?

Tags: google-compute-engine

On Compute Engine we can do Snapshots, which are basically backups. Could you try to figure out how we could create a script to do automated snapshots every day and keep like 4 snapshots, so basically after we have 4, delete the oldest one. This is the only concern of mine on Google Cloud is not having scheduled backups of the server, otherwise I love Compute Engine, its much easier than Amazon to use and its cheaper.

Comment: Script should be in JS or PHP if possible

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. From the looks of it, this is probably better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) because the question is about using Google's features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**
Google Cloud has scheduled backups that can be configured per disk. See [Creating scheduled snapshots for persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots) in the Google Cloud documentation.

**Original Answer**

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) is pretty clear about how to do it:

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot DISK
```

Note, that

> Snapshots are always created based on the last successful snapshot taken

And before you will remove any of your snapshots -- take a look on that diagram:
[image]

[More](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/snapshots) information about API.

Comment: This is how we manually do it manually from interface. I want to execute a script which do it for me as cron

Comment: `gcloud compute disks snapshot DISK` is it looks like "manually"? Why you cannot run `gcloud compute disks snapshot DISK1` from your script by cron?

Comment: How can we do it using PHP?

Comment: Something like `<?php exec("gcloud compute disks snapshot DISK") ?>`?

Comment: Actually you have read the description that I want to create snapshot by deleting last and disk will have many projects

Comment: I mean sir the script did work for me thanks for that. But how about a script which creates new snapshots for me by deleting all old snapshots for each project?

Comment: Go to documentation and look for "delete" method.

Answer (score 31):

**UPDATE**:

The script has changed a lot since I first gave this answer - please see Github repo for latest code: https://github.com/jacksegal/google-compute-snapshot

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I had the same problem, so I created a simple shell script to take a daily snapshot and delete all snapshots over 7 days: https://github.com/Forward-Action/google-compute-snapshot

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin

#
# CREATE DAILY SNAPSHOT
#

# get the device name for this vm
DEVICE_NAME="$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/disks/0/device-name" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")"

# get the device id for this vm
DEVICE_ID="$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")"

# get the zone that this vm is in
INSTANCE_ZONE="$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")"

# strip out the zone from the full URI that google returns
INSTANCE_ZONE="${INSTANCE_ZONE##*/}"

# create a datetime stamp for filename
DATE_TIME="$(date "+%s")"

# create the snapshot
echo "$(gcloud compute disks snapshot ${DEVICE_NAME} --snapshot-names gcs-${DEVICE_NAME}-${DEVICE_ID}-${DATE_TIME} --zone ${INSTANCE_ZONE})"


#
# DELETE OLD SNAPSHOTS (OLDER THAN 7 DAYS)
#

# get a list of existing snapshots, that were created by this process (gcs-), for this vm disk (DEVICE_ID)
SNAPSHOT_LIST="$(gcloud compute snapshots list --regexp "(.*gcs-.*)|(.*-${DEVICE_ID}-.*)" --uri)"

# loop through the snapshots
echo "${SNAPSHOT_LIST}" | while read line ; do

   # get the snapshot name from full URL that google returns
   SNAPSHOT_NAME="${line##*/}"

   # get the date that the snapshot was created
   SNAPSHOT_DATETIME="$(gcloud compute snapshots describe ${SNAPSHOT_NAME} | grep "creationTimestamp" | cut -d " " -f 2 | tr -d \')"

   # format the date
   SNAPSHOT_DATETIME="$(date -d ${SNAPSHOT_DATETIME} +%Y%m%d)"

   # get the expiry date for snapshot deletion (currently 7 days)
   SNAPSHOT_EXPIRY="$(date -d "-7 days" +"%Y%m%d")"

   # check if the snapshot is older than expiry date
if [ $SNAPSHOT_EXPIRY -ge $SNAPSHOT_DATETIME ];
        then
     # delete the snapshot
         echo "$(gcloud compute snapshots delete ${SNAPSHOT_NAME} --quiet)"
   fi
done
```

Comment: The accepted answer regarding differential snapshots is correct, but scripts like this that delete snapshots may still be useful to make your list of snapshots more manageable. And don't worry about deleting snapshots, as the API will move unique blocks into newer snapshots (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#deleting_snapshot)

Answer (score 11):

My solution is slightly simpler. I want to snapshot all disks not just the primary disk.

By listing all disks in the project this handles all servers from one single script - as long as it is run within a gcloud project (and could be modified to run outside a project server too.

To tidy up older snapshots doesn't need such complex date processing as it can be handled from the gcloud command line using a filter

https://gitlab.com/alan8/google-cloud-auto-snapshot

```
#!/bin/bash
# loop through all disks within this project  and create a snapshot
gcloud compute disks list | tail -n +2 | while read DISK_NAME ZONE c3 c4; do
  gcloud compute disks snapshot $DISK_NAME --snapshot-names auto-$DISK_NAME-$(date "+%s") --zone $ZONE 
done
#
# snapshots are incremental and dont need to be deleted, deleting snapshots will merge snapshots, so deleting doesn't loose anything
# having too many snapshots is unwieldy so this script deletes them after 60 days
#
gcloud compute snapshots list --filter="creationTimestamp<$(date -d "-60 days" "+%Y-%m-%d") AND (auto.*)" --uri | while read SNAPSHOT_URI; do
  gcloud compute snapshots delete --quiet $SNAPSHOT_URI
done
#
```

Also note that for OSX users you have to use something like

```
$(date -j -v-60d "+%Y-%m-%d")
```

for the the creationTimestamp filter

Comment: the good point about this script is it's super simple and it just works!

Comment: please note that this script wont work anymore since there is a limit on the number of character (61) for the snapshot names ```Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)``` so you will need to edit the part generating the name of the snapshot

Answer (score 5):

There is now a feature called "Snapshot Schedule" available in GCP.

It still seems to be in Beta, and there is not much documentation on this feature yet.
But it is a straight forward process to enable it.
First you create a snapshot schedule and can assign it to persistent disks after you set it up.

[image: Snapshot Schedule Creation via GUI]

See also the command line reference to create a schedule with corresponding the gcloud command:

```
gcloud beta compute resource-policies create-snapshot-schedule
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/resource-policies/create-snapshot-schedule

To assign the schedule to a persistent disk you can use the command

```
gcloud beta compute disks add-resource-policies
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/disks/add-resource-policies

**Update 2019-02-15:**
Since yesterday there is a [blog announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/introducing-scheduled-snapshots-for-compute-engine-persistent-disk) about the scheduled snapshots feature and also a page in the Compute Engine documentation for [scheduled snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots).

Answer (score 2):

Script assumes $HOSTNAME is the same as disk-name (my primary system disk assumes the same name as the the VM instance or $HOSTNAME -- (change to your liking) ultimately, wherever it says $HOSTNAME, it needs to point to the system disk on your VM.

gcloud creates incremental diff snapshots.  The oldest will contain the most information.  You do not need to worry about creating a full snapshot.  Deleting the oldest will make the new oldest snapshot the primary that future incrementals will base from.  This is all done on Google side logic -- so it is automagic to gcloud.

We have this script set to run on a cron job every hour.  It creates a incremental snapshot (abt 1 to 2GB) and deletes any that are older than retention days.  Google magically resizes the oldest snapshot (which was previously an incremental) to be the base snapshot.  You can test this by deleting the base snapshot and refreshing the snapshot list  (console.cloud.google.com) -- the "magic" occurs in the background and you may need to give it a minute or so to rebase itself.  Afterwards, you'll notice the oldest snapshot is the base and it's size will reflect the used portion of the disk that you are performing the snapshot on.

## $> snapshot

```
#!/bin/bash

    . ~/.bash_profile > /dev/null 2>&1  # source environment for cron jobs
    
    retention=7 #days
    
    zone=`gcloud info|grep zone:|awk -F\[ '{print $2}'|awk -F\] '{print $1}'`
    date=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`
    expire=`date -d "-${retention} days" +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`
    
    snapshots=`gcloud compute snapshots list --regexp "(${HOSTNAME}-.*)" --uri`
    
    # Delete snapshots older than $expire
    for line in "${snapshots[@]}"
    do
      snapshot=`echo ${line}|awk -F\/  '{print $10}'|awk -F\  '{print $1}'`
      snapdate=`echo $snapshot|awk -F\- '{print $3}'`
      if (( $snapdate <= $expire )); then
        gcloud compute snapshots delete $snapshot --quiet
      fi
    done
    
    # Create New Snapshot
    gcloud compute disks snapshot $HOSTNAME --snapshot-name ${HOSTNAME}-${date} --zone $zone --description "$HOSTNAME Disk snapshot ${date}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very rude ruby script to accomplish this task. Please, consider it just as an example from which to take inspiration.

Any feedback to improve it is welcome ;-)

```rb
require 'date'

ARCHIVE = 30 # Days
DISKS   = [] # The names of the disks to snapshot
FORMAT  = '%y%m%d'

today = Date.today
date = today.strftime(FORMAT).to_i
limit = (today - ARCHIVE).strftime(FORMAT).to_i

# Backup
`gcloud compute disks snapshot #{DISKS.join(' ')} --snapshot-names #{DISKS.join("-#{date},")}-#{date}`

# Rotate
snapshots = []
`gcloud compute snapshots list`.split("\n").each do |row|
  name = date
  row.split("\s").each do |cell|
    name = cell
    break
  end
  next if name == 'NAME'
  snapshots << name if name[-6, 6].to_i < limit
end
`yes | gcloud compute snapshots delete #{snapshots.join(' ')}` if snapshots.length > 0
```

Comment: Are you running it on the same machine that you're doing backup or its a separate machine?

Comment: The script runs on the same machine that I'm doing backup. Snapshots are stored elsewhere by google.

Answer (score 1):

in my example, I have a maintenance window to create a snapshot for MySQL. it assumes that the service account has permission to execute gcloud snapshots commands. hope it helps:

```
#!/bin/bash

days_to_keep=7

disk=`curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/disks/1/device-name" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
zone=`curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
project=`curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
zone=`basename ${zone}`
storage_location=`echo ${zone}|sed 's/-[a-z]$//'`


systemctl stop mysqld
sleep 5
# flush file system buffers
sync
# create snapshot
gcloud -q compute disks snapshot ${disk} --project=${project} --snapshot-names=${disk}-$(date +%s) --zone=${zone} --storage-location=${storage_location}

systemctl start mysqld


delete_date=$(date -d "-${days_to_keep} days" "+%Y-%m-%d")

# get list of snapshots to delete
to_del=$(gcloud compute snapshots list  --filter="name ~ ${disk}* AND creationTimestamp<$delete_date" --format "csv[no-heading](name)")

# delete bulk of old snapshots
if [[ ! -z ${to_del} ]]
then
    gcloud compute snapshots delete -q ${to_del}
fi
```

Comment: If I don't have a database in my application, do I need to do this?  I'm confused by the "Run an app flush to disk." instruction on the [gcloud documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#prepare_for_consistency).

Comment: If anyone else is confused about this same point, [this](https://geekflare.com/google-cloud-vm-backup/) article describes the process.  I really ought to summarize it with all the relevant information in a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else I know that `[--set-scheduling]` is a situational gcloud flag and there's a `wait [process]` that will prevent the current command from executing until that process is complete. Combine that with `&&` operator (executes same-statement commands after the previous is completed), stringing this sucker together shouldn't be too hard. Just run it at startup (when you create an instance it has startup command option) and have it count time or make one of the regular maintenance functions trigger the commands. But honestly, why mix syntax if you don't have to?

This could work (don't copy/paste)

```
gcloud config set compute/zone wait [datetime-function] && \
gcloud compute disks snapshot snap1 snap2 snap3 \
        --snapshot-names ubuntu12 ubuntu14 debian8  \
        --description=\
            '--format="multi(\
                info:format=list always-display-title compact,\
                data:format=list always-display-title compact\
                )"'
```

In theory gcloud will set the compute/zone but will have to wait until the time specified. Because of the double ampersand (&&) the next command will not execute until after the first command is complete. I may have gone overboard on the description but I did so for the  sake of showing the simplicity of it, I know it won't work as is but I also know I'm not that far off. Wow after looking at all the code one might believe we're attempting to solve the immortality sequence. I don't think working it out in a bash file is the best way. gcloud made command line for people that don't know command line. We've been taught (or learned... or haven't learned yet) to write code a proper way relative to the environment. I say we apply that here and use the CLOUD SDK to our advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Also, at the time of writing this, Windows instances support Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS), but Linux instances do not.

Hence, you can safely snapshot Windows drives whilst the instance is running using the --guest-flush switch, but not so for Linux drives.

Prior to snapshotting Linux drives, you will need some other mechanism to prepare it for snapshotting i.e. freeze the drive, detach the drive or poweroff the instance.

Answer (score -1):

There's also a 3rd Party service called [VMPower.io](http://VMPower.io) which can automate the capture, retention and restore of snapshots for google cloud. It isn't free but will do what you're looking for without having to code anything.