# Google Compute Engine virtual machine backup strategy

Tags: backup, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

Does Google Compute Engine provide automatic, scheduled backups for virtual machines? I want to backup entire disk, exactly how I can do it manually, Couldn't find it in their documentation, and if not, what are other strategies for scheduling backups you have used?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/createSnapshot) to programmatically do automatic snapshot. A similar question has been answered on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418427/how-to-create-and-rotate-automatic-snapshot).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, recently GCP announced snapshot schedules which can be used to do exactly what you want. You can refer to the [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots) link to set your schedule either by GCP console or gcloud command.