# How to backup a Google Cloud VM running Container-Optimized OS?

Tags: google-container-os

I deployed a Docker image on a Google Compute Engine virtual machine instance (see [containers on compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers)). I would like to perform **regular**, **automatic** backups of this instance and it's disks.

[Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/) has limitations that do not allow to implement solutions like [google-compute-snapshot](https://github.com/jacksegal/google-compute-snapshot) which require to install system packages.

Any recommendations on how should I automate this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of any persistent disk attached to a GCP instance(It doesn't matter whether your VM is having a container-optimized OS or not).

In order to perform automation for a snapshot, you can make use of '[gcloud command for snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot)' with the help of a shell script. This script can then run automatically with the help of a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), which will ultimately produce automation(check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418427/how-to-create-and-rotate-automatic-snapshot) for more details) of the snapshots backups.

Additionally, there is this ongoing '[Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904713)' for automated snapshot management in the Google Cloud Platform. You can suggest your valuable comments there as well.

Comment: Thanks,  feature request link is a google-only link, can you share the public one?

Comment: Corrected. Check the link again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your container related data are being stored on a persistent disk. Then Install the Google Cloud SDK so as to get gcloud compute commands on your local machine. Or use the readily available  Google Cloud Shell .

Then take snapshot of your persistent disk. To ensure that a snapshot is consistent with the desired state of the persistent disk, it is best practice to pause it. Though you can create a snapshot of a persistent disk even while your applications write data to the disk.

Use:

```
$ gcloud compute disks snapshot [DISK_NAME]
```

This the only command you need to run to have a screenshot of your root or data volume.

Comment: With 'container related data', are you sure you can store the container metadata in the disk? (for example, the docker image name used by the Container Optimized OS)