# How to automate backups of Windows instances on the Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

There is an awesome way to backup Linux instances on GCP (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418427/how-to-create-and-rotate-automatic-snapshot) and [here](https://www.onepagezen.com/automatic-backups-google-cloud/))

I want to do the same for Windows instances. I'm new to the google cloud. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend check this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots), More specifically this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot) which will help you to create a Windows persistent disk snapshot.

Comment: These are all manual ways which I am already doing. I want an automated way as described for Linux instances above.

Comment: please note that there is no Google built in method for this, you will need to write a powershell script to take the snapshots similar to the bash scripts

Answer (score 0):

Google has added a new feature where you can schedule backups!

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots